# Combination sports odds question

Tags: combinatorics

There are 10 games between 20 teams being played.  I want to know how many combinations of 5 I can make from those 20 teams.  Order doesn't matter.  I only want to pick winners so only 1 team per game per combination of 5.  I can find this by multiplying 20x18x16x14x12 = 967,680.  This number is including all of the repeats; how do I subtract the repeats?

If I didn't need to pick winners then the answer would be 15,504 but I can only pick 1 team from each contest so I know the answer has to be smaller than this number.

Answer (score 0):

Write down the 20 teams as 10 pairs (each pair representing a game).

You then need to select 5 out of the 10 games, and in each game, select one of two teams.

There are ${10 \choose 5} = 252$ ways to select the rows, and $2^5=32$ ways to pick the winners in the rows, so $252*32 = 8064$ ways.

In general, to pick $k$ distinct items out of $n$, you can pick $k$ items, ORDERED, from $n$, and then divide by the number of ways to shuffle $k$ items. For instance, to pick 2 items out of 5, the ordered choices are

`1 2
   1 3
   1 4
   1 5
   2 1
   2 3
   2 4
   2 5
   3 1
   3 2
   3 4
   3 5
   4 1
   4 2
   4 3
   4 5
   5 1
   5 2
   5 3
   5 4`

One scheme for producing these is to say "pick the first number, and draw a line though it; then pick the second number from the un-struck-out numbers." There are 5 ways to pick the first number, and 4 ways to pick the next number. (That's why, in the list above, each possible "first number" appears 4 times). More generally, there are $n$ ways to pick the first number, $n-1$ ways to pick the second, ..., $n - k + 1$ ways to pick the $k$th one. 
So it sounds as if the total number of possibilities would be $n \cdot (n-1) \cdots (n-k+1)$.

But as you see in the example above, both "1 2" and "2 1" appear, and we don't want to count these as the same. Since in the general case, we have $k$ numbers, how many times is each group of $k$ repeated? Well, for a given collection of $k$ numbers, we can form lists in many ways: there are $k$ ways to pick the first number, $k-1$ choices for the second, and so on, with 2 choices for the second-to-last number, and only one choice for the last one. We have to divide our previous count by $k \cdot (k-1) \cdots 2 \cdot 1$ to account for this overcounting!

So the final result is that the number of ways to choose $k$ things from a group of $n$ is 
$$
\frac{n \cdot (n-1) \cdots (n - k + 1) } {k \cdot (k-1) \cdots 2 \cdot 1}.
$$
In our case of $n = 10$ rows, from which we want to choose $k = 5$, this becomes
$$
\frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6} {5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}= 252.
$$

Comment: John Hughes thanks for your answer it looks like the right answer to me but I don't understand how you got 252 ways of picking the rows.  Could you explain further?

Comment: Your the man, thanks.